# Comparing a sequence of letters to a list of words in python

Tags: python

I have a list of letters which is in a particular order (think of old school texting, so my sequence of buttons here is 4266532)

```
letters = [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['j', 'k', 'l'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

and a list of words

```
words = ['i', 'am', 'an', 'old', 'man']
```

I want to see how many matched sentences there are for this sequence of letters compared to this word list.

For example the sequence of letters could equal 'i am old' or 'i an old'

EDIT: To clarify what I mean by sequence

on old phones that still have buttons instead of touch screen. each button (or number) has letters that are attached to it. For example the number/button '2' has the letters `['a','b','c']` attached to it. The number/button '3' has the letters `['d,'e','f']` attached to it. So my `letters` list above displays what letters could appear on the screen when you push `4266532`

Comment: You could brute force it pretty easily, how large is the data ? Also you have not specified the logic of what is considered a sequence. Is old man and considering you consider `'i an old'` even `an man` valid?

Comment: it is for a university assignment, so the data won't be much larger than what I am showing, they may test against different word lists and letter sequences but the size will be similar @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Will the results always be in order, ie from your `words` object?

Comment: Well, sort the sublists and at least then you can short circuit. Can any words be used together?

Comment: yes they will be in order @enderland and the letters can only be used once. So if i iterated across letters, i can only take one letter from each sublist to help in forming a word

Comment: `['m', 'n', 'o']` appears twice, do you have to use one letter from each?

Comment: yes thats correct @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Ah ok, you have `['m', 'n', 'o']` twice for 66. What about the order of the words?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your full criteria is but since your lists are going to be small you can do something like:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations, chain
letters = [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['m', 'n', 'o'],['m', 'n', 'o'], ['j', 'k', 'l'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
allowed = set(chain.from_iterable(letters))
words = ['i', 'am', 'an', 'old', 'man']

for phrase in combinations(words, 3):
    phrase_c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(phrase))
    if any((v > 1 and k not in "mno") or k not in allowed for k, v in phrase_c.items()):
        continue
    print(phrase)
```

Which would give you:

```
('i', 'am', 'old')
('i', 'an', 'old')
('i', 'old', 'man')
```

If words is always a subset of the letter you can remove the `if k not in "mno"`

if you have to be in order then it is simpler, just make sure each letter from the phrase appears in the subsets and in the correct order:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations, chain

letters = [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['j', 'k', 'l'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

words = ['i', 'am', 'an', 'old', 'man']

for phrase in combinations(words, 3):
    for ind, letter in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(phrase)):
         if ind >= len(letters) or letter not in letters[ind]:
            break
    else:
        print(phrase)
```

Which would give you:

```
('i', 'am', 'old')
('i', 'an', 'old')
```

If you sort words based on the letter order and filter words that don't contain any letters from the set you can reduce the complexity quite a bit. You can also consider  the fact that you can only create at most phrases that have 6 letters i.e `4266532`

Comment: okay this will put me on the right track, although ('i', 'old', 'man') should not be an output because it is not in the 426653 sequence of letters. Also I've never seen 'collections' or 'itertools' so I'll have to have a read up on those but thank you for that, at least it is a step in the right direction

Comment: So it has to  be in the exact same order?

Comment: Yes, perhaps the image above will explain it better than I have

Comment: does combinations(words, 3) mean it will only produce 3 words?

Comment: Yes, you can extend it from to any range but if you consider the fact that you can only use 6 letters, the phrases have to start with g,h or i you can greatly reduce the problem size.

Comment: okay, is the range necessary ? because say I changed the word list and the letter sequence, I could potentially produce four words. Of course I could manually change the range to '4' but this would be inefficient having to change the range every time I change the word list or the sequence

Comment: Well you can only have words with at most six letters so you have very few combinations to make.You can use another loop from 2-7 and pass in the range to go to

Comment: I think it will be wise for me to understand itertools more, then I'll be able to edit the code accordingly, thanks for you help

Comment: No worries, like I said there are many ways to optimize the code but you should have enough to get you started. Just make sure you check that phrases contain exactly six letters. i.e  `if sum(map(len, phrase)) != len(letters)`